# Will IntelliTrace(tm) (historical debugging) be available for unmanaged c++ in future versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2010, intellitrace, historical-debugging

I love the idea of [historical debugging in VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915(VS.100).aspx).

However, I am really disappointed that unmanaged C++ is left out.

> IntelliTrace supports debugging Visual
>   Basic and C# applications that use
>   .NET version 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, or 4. You
>   can debug most applications, including
>   applications that were created by
>   using ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF,
>   Windows Workflow, and WCF.
>   IntelliTrace does not support
>   debugging C++, script, or other
>   languages. Debugging of F#
>   applications is supported on an
>   experimental basis.

(editorial) [This is really poor support in my opinion.  .NET is less in need of this assistance than unmanaged c++.  I an getting a little tired of the status of plain old C++ and its second-class status in the MS tools world. Yes, I realize it is probably WAAY easier to implement this with .NET and MS are pushing .NET as the future, and yes, I know that C++ is an "old" language, but that does not diminish the fact that there are lots of C++ apps out there and there will continue to be more apps built with C++.  I sincerely hope MS has not dropped C++ as a supported developer tool/language- that would be a shame.]

Does anyone know if there are plans for it to support C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/10/22/intellitrace-is-not-available-why.aspx) they "hope to fix this limitation in the future."

Answer (score 2):

If at all possible, you can compile your C++ code in GDB which has reverse-debugging capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

"Unmanaged C++" is a loose term. It can include raw assembly. Basically, each instruction can change memory in an essentially unpredictable way. IntelliTrace only works decently because it can grok IL. This is no coincidence, IL was designed to be much more suitable for automatic analysis than x86 assembly.

Comment: I understand the challenges.  My question was not about how hard or easy it is - it was about whether it will be done.

Comment: And I would be more than happy to have limitations in watching memory that was touch via asm.  A sort-of functional product can sometimes still be hugely helpful.

Comment: Even for IL they are not recording the complete state. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2010/03/16/intellitrace-what-we-collect.aspx. A similar technology can definitely be applied to native code.

Comment: @Suma: how would you identify the function arguments if a call is made from one bit of assembly to another? You don't have function prototypes, and memory addresses are pretty much untyped.

Comment: I guess you are correct, I admit I did not think much about the problem, and even my knowledge of how IL works is marginal (at best). Most likely the technology can be applied to Debug (unoptimized) compiled code only for native code.